# Expose multiple objects through module with constructor in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, node-modules

I created a module in nodejs where I wish to expose it's constants too. But this particular module contains a dependency which is provided at construction time i.e. dependency injection.

this is module1

```
const STORE_TYPE = {
  STORE1: 1,
  STORE2: 2
};

function service(dependency1) {
  this.dep = dependency1;
}

service.prototype.doSomething = function(param1, store) {
  if (STORE_TYPE.STORE1 == store) {
    return this.dep.get(param1);
  } else {
    return "something";
  }
};

module.exports = service;
```

I'm using module1 here:

```
var dep = require('./dep');
var dep1 = new otherService(dep);
var service = require('./service')(dep1);

function getData() {
  return service.doSomething(id, /*this is module1 constant*/1);
}
```

How do I refere to module1's constants if module1 has a constructor.

I don't wish to add separate method only to create **service** since callee needs to perform multiple steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`service.js`

```
exports.STORE_TYPE = {
  STORE1: 1,
  STORE2: 2
};

exports.service = function service(dependency1) {
  this.dep = dependency1;
}

service.prototype.doSomething = function(param1, store) {
  if (STORE_TYPE.STORE1 == store) {
    return this.dep.get(param1);
  } else {
    return "something";
  }
};
```

Using that module

`app.js`

```
const service = require('./service').service;

const STORE_STYLE = require('./service').STORE_TYPE;
```